# Running scripts from another directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

Quite often, the script I want to execute is not located in my current working directory and I don't really want to leave it.

Is it a good practice to run scripts (BASH, Perl etc.) from another directory? Will they usually find all the stuff they need to run properly?

If so, what is the best way to run a "distant" script? Is it

```
. /path/to/script
```

or

```
sh /path/to/script
```

and how to use `sudo` in such cases? This, for example, doesn't work:

```
sudo . /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call your script using only the whole path, without the dot `.`:

```
/path/to/script
```

`sudo` also works fine:

```
sudo /path/to/script
```

> Will they usually find all the stuff they need to run properly?

Do you mean like, "will my script find the files which are in the same folder?" That depends of your code. For example, if you have the script `/tmp/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
```

If you invoke it from your home folder, it will run `ls` in your home:

```
test@ubuntu:~:/tmp/test.sh
Desktop     Dropbox         Imagens  NetBeansProjects     Público     
Documentos  Modelos    R          Vídeos
```

In this situation, `dirname` is your ally:

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(dirname $0)
ls $current
```

Running it from your home folder, it gives:

```
test@ubuntu:~:/tmp/test.sh
acroread_1000_1000     hiRF7yLSOD              pulse-2L9K88eMlGn7   
unity_support_test.0    clementine-art-jt5332.jpg
```

which is the content of my `/tmp/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Common *nix practice for user scripts is to put them in your bin directory.  That way, the script will be searched for by default when you type the name from the command line.

Your bin (binary) directory should be in your home folder so the full path would be `/home/yourusername/bin`. (Obviously change `yourusername` to your login name.)

The bin directory should have the following permissions if you run `ls -lh` from the terminal: `drwxr-xr-x`

By default when you make a directory with the terminal you have the following permissions set: `drwxrwxr-x`

The only thing you need to change is the group permission, but for I will walk you through each step from the terminal (assuming you don't already have a bin):

- Open a terminal ([Ctrl] + [Alt] + t)
- Create the binary directory: `mkdir bin`
- Now either use the GUI or CLI to copy your scripts to `/bin`.
- Now we have to change some permissions so that everything is set up
  correctly:
- chmod -R 755 bin
- This sets the owner (you) to read, write and execute, groups and
  others to read and execute the scripts. The -R means recursive or set
  the permissions for all the files in the directory as well.

For more help on file permissions see this [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

Now, you can just type `myscript` to execute your scripts - you do not have to be in the directory. You don't need the . / or anything!

For sudo it's a little different as you *will* have to define the full path to the script file.

Comment: Is it possible for new scripts added to or created in the script directory to pick up the executable permission automatically, perhaps with a sticky bit?